# Newtonsoft.Json - Does it communicate over internet

Tags: json.net

We use the library Newtonsoft.Json in our project and based on a customer request we are trying to figure out If the library communicates over to Internet any time during the course of operations?

It will be helpful if someone can confirm this.

Not applicable - Haven't tried anything for this yet

Comment: it is open source. you can read the source code.

Comment: I have never seen anything in the source code of Newtonsoft.Json which communicates over the internet, however this is a question best addressed to Newtonsoft itself by opening an issue [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/).  You could also search the source code [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src).

Comment: Of course it's possible some type being deserialized or serialized could communicate over the internet during the [de]serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99.999% sure it does not communicate over the internet for normal JSON serialization/deserialization operations.

Note: I am not associated with Newtonsoft

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.
I did went through the code and could not find any calls to outside.